# Vpn . Nps . Active directory . Strongswan ikev2

Tags: linux, active-directory, vpn, strongswan, ikev2

please help me
I configured a strongswan IKEV2 On Centos7 vps
and NPS and Active Directory for my authentication and accounting(radius) on windows server 2016 vps
when i want to connect to my ikev2 vpn on windows 10 i get this error:

### the remote connection was denied because the username and password combination you provided is not recognized or the selected authentication protocol is not permitted on the remote access server

this is my IPSEC.CONF

config setup

charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2, mgr 2"

uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn

auto=add

compress=no

type=tunnel

keyexchange=ikev2

fragmentation=yes

forceencaps=yes

ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha1,3des-sha1-modp1024!

dpdaction=clear

dpddelay=300s

rekey=no

left=%any

leftauth=pubkey

leftid=@vpn.cr-51-test.local

leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/vpn.cr-51-test.local.crt.pem

leftsendcert=always

leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0

lefthostaccess=yes

leftfirewall=yes

right=%any

rightid=%any

rightauth=eap-radius

rightgroups="CN=VPN_USERS/CN=Users"

rightsourceip=10.10.0.0/24

rightdns=192.150.150.10

rightsendcert=never

rightfirewall=yes

eap_identity=%identity

---

EAP-RADIUS.conf

load = yes

...

secret = radius secret
server = radius ip address

---

ipsec.secrets:

domain or vpnip : RSA vpnhostkey.der

: PSK "radius secret"

---

on NPS server and active directory

i configured radius

Freindly name: vpn

Addresss (IP or DNS): STRONGSWAN IP ADDRESS

Shared secret: RADIUS SECRET

Comment: Sounds a bit like my issue with Windows clients due to how username and password is exchanged with strongswan. Have you tried adding `eap_start = yes` to `EAP-RADIUS.conf`?

Comment: yes brother , on etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/charon/eap-radius.conf

Comment: Also: Windows does not pass username to `eap_identity`, so set to `%any` instead of `%identity`. But for more help: Please past output from server log during the moment a client tries to connect along with your question. There are a lot of insight gained from reading the log.

Comment: i change it to %any , not working